# Don't know how to structure a "story" application in ember

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm trying to create an application using Ember.js.

You click on one thing, and it brings you to the next option.

Click again, brought to the next option, and so on and so forth for 10 questions.

I'm having a really hard time thinking about how I'd like to construct it.  The 10 questions have the possibility of being dynamic, and since you have to go from one to the next, it doesn't make sense to have a URL for every option since you'll be working through it one at a time.

Like, I don't want the url to end up like:

```
http://somesite.com/#/question1/option3/question2/option4/question3/option1/question4/option2/question5/option2/question6/option2/question7/option2/question8/option2/question9/option2/question10/option2
```

It's just not practical...  At least, it doesn't seem practical to me.

Are there any examples of generating multiple views to be used with the same template on the same page?

Ergh.  I wish I had a better way to ask this.  I really want to like Ember.js, but the fact that it places so much on the Router and the URL, makes it difficult for me to imagine how to structure this in the best way.

Comment: What's the template going to be based on?  It seems to me like you have 10 models (each a question with a related answer).  Will the questions be a common set of templates?

Comment: The template for each of the questions is the same one.  Then on the side there's a template that's shared between the questions that shows different answers for each question as you're clicking through.  At least, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could organize it:

```
BIG_GIANT_ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    question_text: 'I am the first question',
    answers: [{
      answer_text: 'I am an answer',
      next_question_id: 2
    },{
      answer_text: 'I am another answer',
      next_question_id: 3
    }
  },
  //another question object
]
```

So each question has an id, and each answer mentions another id to keep the story going.

If that's an OK setup for you, here's some code:

First, you can have a dynamic route like "somesite.com/#/questions/4"

In your router you can build a URL like that:

```
YourStoryApp.Router.map(function() {
  //other routes
  this.resource('questions', function() {
    this.resource('question', {path: '/:question_id'}
  });
});
```

Details here: [http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments][1]

Then in the routes, you can return either that giant list of questions you have, or an individual one:

```
YourStoryApp.QuestionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return BIG_GIANT_ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS;
  }
});

YourStoryApp.QuestionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('questions').findBy('id', params.question_id);
  }
});
```

Now whenever you visit '/questions/4', you'll get just that question from your BIG_GIANT_ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS.

Finally this could be your question template (with some more html):

```
Question {{id}}
{{question_text}}

Answers
{{#each answers}}
  {{#link-to 'question' next_question_id}}
    {{answer_text}}
  {{/link-to}}
{{/each
```

OK that's a long slab of code, I hope some of it helps with the brainstorming. And I apologize for any typos/errors/etc.

Comment: These are some fantastic ideas.  You don't need to apologize, you're offering help, which I truly appreciate.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because you really did give me a good leg up.  I was trying to fight against Ember, the Router, and the URLs, but I guess it doesn't really make sense to think about it in only one way.